# Get all parents of all children in Rust Vec

Tags: vector, rust, hashmap

I have a `Vec<(String, String)>` where first String is child and second String is parent.
How can I make a `HashMap<String, Vec<String>>` where key is child and value is array of parents?

Example:

| Child | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| "" | "Child1" |
| "Child1" | "Parent1" |
| "Parent1" | "Parent2" |
| "Child2" | "Parent3" |
| "Parent3" | "Parent2" |
| "Parent2" | "" |
| "" | "Child2" |

Expected result:

| Child | Parents |
| --- | --- |
| "Child1" | ["Parent1", "Parent2"] |
| "Child2" | ["Parent3", "Parent2"] |

Comment: Do you want to move the strings from the vector into the map, or clone them?

Comment: I want to move.

Comment: It looks like the empty string is a sentinel; is it guaranteed to never occur in any other context?  Are all other children guaranteed to have exactly one parent?  If not (to either question) how should those cases be handled?

Comment: Furthermore, is there any limit to the number of children that a parent may have?